# Submit manuscript to tier A conference or wait and submit to A* conference?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science

Suppose you have a manuscript and you have just missed the deadline for an A* conference. Should I submit to the next tier A conference or wait until for the A* conference to come around again?

I am in the computer science field, hence the emphasis on conferences, rather than journals.

Comment: I would ignore the A versus A* nonsense and submit to the next conference where people will care about the result.

Comment: @JeffE Although I agree with you on principle, if you (or one of your students) have a very strong paper that you think will be accepted to FOCS or SODA and you missed the deadline, would you send it to a slightly worse conference?

Comment: I think this is unanswerable as is, because it depends so much on individual factors. I imagine it depends a lot on whether it's time-sensitive - does this need to be out there as a basis for future publications? Is somebody else likely to do it between now and next year? Does one of the authors need it on their CV soon? And so forth.

Answer (score 6):

> Suppose you have a manuscript and you have just missed the deadline for an A* conference. Should I submit to the next tier A conference or wait until for the A* conference to come around again?

This depends on a number of factors:

- How likely do you think your paper is to be accepted in the A* conference? If this is your absolute best, cream-of-the-crop paper and you are confident it will go through, then submitting to a weaker conference just because you did not want to wait will feel like waste down the road. If the A* conference felt like a long shot anyway, go ahead and submit now.
- How likely are you to get scooped? If you are doing cutting-edge research in a trending topic, you may want to go for the A conference simply because you are afraid that somebody else may publish before you if you don't.
- How important is timely publishing for your content? Many great research papers are in essence timeless, but occasionally one has produced a paper that is of value to the community right now, but which may be much less interesting in a year (e.g., some empirical studies in fast-moving fields are like that). In that case you should submit to the A conference now, because there is a very real danger that the paper will not be good enough for the A* paper in a year anyway.
- How important is having the paper out soon for your career progression? E.g., if you are handing in your PhD in a year, or plan to be on the job market in a year, or plan to hand in this selective personal grant in the next year, then having another published A paper may be better than a potential A* paper that comes "too late".
- How much value is (in your field and your circles) placed on the "esteem" of the venue? That is, what do you estimate how much more valuable the same paper will be for your career if published in an A* venue rather than an A venue? In a perfect world, it would not matter. In the real world, as for instance in my field, the venue a publication appeared in is ultimately more important in career decisions on all levels than the actual content.

Comment: You can always submit to arXiv, then you won't get scooped and you will get your result out in a timely manner for the benefit of other researchers.

Answer (score 3):

My choice of whether to bother with the "tippy-top" conferences depends strongly on their size.  When you have a highly selective but also very large conference like AAAI, I'm quite comfortable to submit, since there is enough space for papers that the decision is likely to depend primarily on the quality of my paper.

For the "super-important" conferences that are single-track, however, there is too much selective pressure.  Because these have become so high-stakes and because such a terribly small percentage of work can be accepted, the decision is often less about "Is this a good paper?" and more about "Are there any reasons that we can use to eliminate this paper?"  This creates an environment in which there is much more randomness in acceptance, as well as a danger of significantly increased group-think, clique politics, and preference for safe incremental thinking.  Thus, I am unlikely to bother prioritizing them too strongly.  To be fair, however, these hyper-selective conferences also do not dominate my subfield or strongly determine my career future, and thus I can afford to do so.

If you or your co-authors are in a subfield and career stage where the difference between an "blessed" conference and an almost-as-good conference is going to make a big difference to university administrators or an in-group that dominates your field, though, then sure, prefer the "blessed" conference.

Comment: This sort of ignores the actual question here. The OP was not asking "should I submit to an A* conference rather than an A conference", but rather "should I wait for a longer time for an A* conference or submit to an A conference right now".

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear in my answer: submit now.

Answer (score -3):

I would submit just to get feedback.  If it is an accept, then re-read the answers here and decide whether you want withdraw and submit it to the A* conference if the comments are very positive.  Otherwise, if it is lukewarm, and an accept, then you at least have a conf paper.  If it is a reject maybe a self reflection is in order.  If there are bugs then you can fix them so you have a better paper for the A* conf.

Comment: Withdrawing an accepted paper, because you think the conference isn't good enough, will not go down well.

Comment: I doubt it. There are tonnes of excuses you can use to withdraw a paper; e.g,. there is a flaw in lemma x.

Comment: That excuse won't hold water if you submit the same paper to a different conference later.